# Domain on clientHold from 4 days ago, expires in a year, will it be available before?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

So this domain I want is on clientHold status. It's set to expire in about a year from now.
Will it end that clientHold state before expiring or will it stay like that for a full year?

Thank you!

Comment: We get questions like this periodically from people who want to snatch up a domain that is currently registered. Some even look for loop-holes and want to steal a domain or force someone to give up a domain. The advice here is always the same. Give it up. There is nothing you can do short of using someone like GoDaddy to do the work for you. And even then, the odds are extremely remote you will end up with it unless you have lots of cash to burn. Let it go. Find another one.

Comment: I'm not trying to snatch a domain from someone, it's actually mine and because of a stupid repressive law in my country, it's been put in that state. If I had registered somewhere more civilized, this wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Sorry! ;-) We do get the questions I described quite a lot. It is frustrating. Like I said, most are looking for a loop-hole and want us to help them discover or use the loop-hole. Some just hover waiting. What is sad is that these folks are good people, however, they are stuck going down a rabbit hole by focusing too much on one domain name. This is one of the reasons why I like to be so frank on the subject. I try and jolt people awake sometimes. I mean no offense. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The domain will be subject to deletion once your registrar has conducted its investigation. Just like with all other legal disputes, investigations take time. If you want the domain released faster then you need to contact your domain registrar to provide them evidence that you are, or not the rightful owner or comply to the policies set out in there terms of use.

*Short answer is that you need to contact your registrar:*

> This status code tells your domain's registry to not activate your
>   domain in the DNS and as a consequence, it will not resolve. It is an
>   uncommon status that is usually enacted during legal disputes,
>   non-payment, or when your domain is subject to deletion.
>
> Often, this status indicates an issue with your domain that needs
>   resolution. If so, you should contact your registrar to resolve the
>   issue. If your domain does not have any issues, but you need it to
>   resolve, you must first contact your registrar and request that they
>   remove this status code.